# Android Game Laundcher Library Drawer

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to implement a drawer similar to the drawer of Game Launcher in android.
I know how to use react modal or react-native-modal library to create a drawer, but i don't know how to exactly simulate the behavior of the game launcher's drawer.
Also, I don't know what is the keyword the to search for guide or to see code examples for it.

So if anyone can help with a guide or open source code I will predicate it.

Here the screen shots of the game launcher drawer behavior

[game launcher drawer behavior 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shrpp.jpg)

[game launcher drawer behavior 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWm9b.jpg)

[game launcher drawer behavior 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj4Pd.jpg)